# How to use CompletableFuture for async fetch from database

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I am working with the help of ChatGPT on my first study project with CompletableFuture from Java.
The idea is to use multi threading and see how much can the fetch performance be improved.
I am getting 5000 random orders from a DB of 6 000 000.

Version A:

```
    public List<Order> getOrdersInParallel(int numberOfThreads) {
        List<Long> orderIds = GeneratorService.getOrderIds(DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
 
        List<CompletableFuture<Order>> orderFutures = getFutures(orderIds, executor);
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(orderFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
 
        return allFutures.thenApplyAsync(future -> resolveOrders(orderFutures)).join();
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/LwrDs6CS

Version B:

```
    public List<Order> getOrdersInParallel(int numberOfThreads) {
 
        List<Long> orderIds = GeneratorService.getOrderIds(DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
 
        List<CompletableFuture<Order>> orders = orderIds.stream()
                .map(orderId -> fetchOrderAsync(orderId, executor))
                .toList();
 
        CompletableFuture<List<Order>> combinedOrders = CompletableFuture
                .allOf(orders.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenApplyAsync(orderFuture -> resolveOrders(orders));
 
        return combinedOrders.join();
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/KA8JtuV1

A was the original, B is an attempt to improve it.

Can you explain to me which version would you prefer (and why)?
Have I missed something or done it wrong?
How would you solve this problem ?